# Error with facebook comment in asp.net -(URL Rewritng)

Tags: facebook-comments

Using the fb:comments I am getting the following error:
Example : `Warning: http://www.goodnewstab.com/article/HealthTechnolgy/Health/Cuts-That-Save-A-Millon-Hearts is unreachable.`

What i am doing:

URL rewriting using .net 4.0

I have included the folling code base

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="358301920913978" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="The Good News Tab" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.goodnewstab.com/article/HealthTechnolgy/Health/Cuts-That-Save-A-Millon-Hearts/" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Cuts That Save A Millon Hearts" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Cuts That Save A Millon Hearts" />

    <!-- FACEBOOK JAVASCRIPT-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
           // js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=";
              js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=358301920913978";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <!-- ================= -->

</head>
<body>
<fb:comments  href='http://www.goodnewstab.com/article/HealthTechnolgy/Health/Cuts-That-Save-A-Millon-Hearts' num_posts='10' width='570'></fb:comments>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.goodnewstab.com%2Farticle%2FHealthTechnolgy%2FHealth%2FCuts-That-Save-A-Millon-Hearts

Your UL automatically redirects to http://www.goodnewstab.com/home, and that one causes a circular redirect by redirecting to itself again: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.goodnewstab.com%2Fhome

Comment: please let me know how can i fix this.i am relay confused.

Comment: We can not look into your server – the only one you can find out why it does what it does, is _you_.